# RecursiveTask thread is not blocked by join()

Tags: java, multithreading, executor, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I have the following code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(1);
        ForkJoinPool workStealingPool = (ForkJoinPool)executorService;
        RecursiveRunnable recursiveRunnable = new RecursiveRunnable(5);
        workStealingPool.invoke(recursiveRunnable);
    }
}
public class RecursiveRunnable extends RecursiveTask<Integer> implements Runnable {
    private final int n;

    public RecursiveRunnable(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    protected Integer compute() {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.println("Thread started, threadId=" + thread.getId() + " n=" + n +  " activeCount=" + Thread.activeCount());
        if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
        }
        RecursiveRunnable f1 = new RecursiveRunnable(n - 1);
        f1.fork();
        RecursiveRunnable f2 = new RecursiveRunnable(n - 2);
        f2.fork();
        int result = 0;
        result = f2.get() + f1.get();
        System.out.println("Thread finished,  threadId=" + thread.getId() + " n=" + n +  " activeCount=" + Thread.activeCount() + " result=" + result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        compute();
    }
}
```

I expect from the code not to open new threads in the ***fork()*** statment,
 since the **parallelism is 1**.
But the output of this code is:

> Thread started, threadId=11 n=5 activeCount=3 
>  Thread started,
>   threadId=11 n=3 activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=1
>   activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=2 activeCount=3
>   
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=0 activeCount=3 
>  Thread
>   started, threadId=11 n=1 activeCount=3 
>  Thread finished, 
>   threadId=11 n=2 activeCount=3 result=1 
>  Thread finished, 
>   threadId=11 n=3 activeCount=3 result=2 
>  Thread started,
>   threadId=11 n=4 activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=2
>   activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=0 activeCount=3
>   
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=1 activeCount=3 
>  Thread
>   finished,  threadId=11 n=2 activeCount=3 result=1 
>  Thread
>   started, threadId=11 n=3 activeCount=3 
>  Thread started,
>   threadId=11 n=1 activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=2
>   activeCount=3 
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=0 activeCount=3
>   
>  Thread started, threadId=11 n=1 activeCount=3 
>  Thread
>   finished,  threadId=11 n=2 activeCount=3 result=1 
>  Thread
>   finished,  threadId=11 n=3 activeCount=3 result=2 
>  Thread
>   finished,  threadId=11 n=4 activeCount=3 result=3 
>  Thread
>   finished,  threadId=11 n=5 activeCount=3 result=5

From the output print it looks like we have 12 threads alive at one time.
How new threads are open although the **parallelism is 1** ?

Comment: If I set "new RecursiveRunnable(20)" and "Executors.newWorkStealingPool(3)"  I get in the prints "threadId=11", "threadId=12" , "threadId=13 "

Comment: Mmm, you see the same thread id all the time, but say “it looks like we have 12 threads alive”? All you see, is that the code is executed by a single thread. In other words, as your title is already saying, the thread is not blocked by `join`. Except that you are never invoking `join()`, but `get()`…